# Error converting varchar to float with German formats

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, number-formatting, type-conversion

Using German number formats I am uploading a CSV with a column `amount`into my SQL Server DB as part of an SSIS package.

[image: SSIS Data Flow]

This package was created via the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. The column `amount` got assigned `datatype (varchar (50), null)` in SQL Server.

Sanple data looks like this:

```
Declare @amount varchar(50)
Set @amount = '1245,89'
Select @amount
```

For subsequent operations I want to convert this to datatype float:

```
select 
convert(float,@amount)
```

This gives me an error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 5 Error converting data type varchar
>   to float.

Changing the decimal separator from '`,`' to '`.`' works:

```
Declare @amount varchar(50)
Set @amount = '1245.89'
Select @amount

select 
convert(float,@amount) + 3
```

This is what I want but I am wondering if it is possible to either achieve this directly inside the Import/Export Wizard or at least without replacing '`,`' by '`.`'. Is there any setting that I have to change to German, other than this?:

[image: Regional/Language settings]

Comment: Have you tried using `PARSE` instead of `CONVERT`?

Comment: No, how exactly does this look like for my example? This function is unknown to me so far

Comment: Well I found the documentation just by searching - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx

Comment: Another option would be to try to change the export so that the `amount` column is a more appropriate datatype to start with...

Comment: ah sorry I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 which does not support this function. Regarding changing the export inside the SSIS package: this is what I tried as well but then I get 124589 (datatype float!) instead of 1245,89.